# GCP Compute Disks - Understanding the clone limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, clone, google-compute-disk

I'm confused by this limitation on disk cloning.  Earlier on, it says `You can also delete the source disk without any risk of deleting the clone.  The ability to clone disks is useful for duplicating production data to debug without disturbing production`  This makes me think that they are segregated and safe.

But further down, it says `You can create at most 1000 total disk clones of a given source disk.`

If I clone a clone, does that count against the original source, or just against Clone 1's limit?  Are there any other ways that these are entangled with each other?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-disk-from-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not count the original source and you can also clone the newly cloned disk again with the 1000 limit as it will be treated as an original.

The one that is related to an original image would be the [Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) and it reflects the contents of a persistent disk in a concrete instant in time.

Snapshots are also less expensive than Cloning as it uses less disk space and is good for a quick backup and restore. Using snapshots may be simpler for most cases.

Comment: Any idea why there is the 1000 clone limit then?  Is it just to stop stupid mistakes, like infinite loops cloning disks?

Comment: Possibly, but there is no documented reason for it

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to clone a disk clone ?
Have-you already use the limitation of 1000 clones ?

With informations in the documentation we can just think that a clone is just a new disk with a other 1000 clones.

Comment: A disk and a disk clone should be identical.  I may need another clone, and probably wouldn't be tracking which one was the original pre-clone.  Since they are supposed to be identical and unique, I shouldn't need to track which one was the original.